# How to determine "number of concurrent sessions" for all users on a server

Tags: rhel, users, authentication, limit

I am trying to determine the total number of concurrent sessions on a server to determine a good number for the `maxlogins` option in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. How is the number of sessions calculated in relation to the value set for `maxlogins` and is there a way to check that number via the command line?

Comment: Have you try with `who`?

Comment: I've done `who` and `w`, but was unsure if the number of users in the list those commands generate directly corresponds to the number set by `maxlogins`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limits.conf` is used by by `pam_limits`, so I suspect the answer to "How is the number of session calculated?" is "the number of times the `pam_limits` module was used as part of a PAM authentication process".

So that means:

- The `login` command
- `su`
- `sudo`
- Etc.

Look in `/etc/pam.d` for an authoritative list of things that include `pam_limits` in their session setup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It seems unlikely that there is a simple way of determining everything that has a session at once, but this should help